# JavaScript RegExp matches binary data

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm using RegExp to match a series of bytes other than `0x1b` from the sequence `[0xcb, 0x98, 0x1b]` :

```
var r = /[^\x1b]+/g;
r.exec(new Buffer([0xcb, 0x98, 0x1b]));
console.log(r.lastIndex);
```

I expected that the pattern would match `0xcb, 0x98` and `r.lastIndex == 2`, but it matches `0xcb` only and `r.lastIndex == 1`.
Is that a bug or something?

Comment: What is expected result? `[203, 152]`?

Comment: Yes, [0xcb, 0x98]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regexp.exec()` implicitly converts its argument to a string and `Buffer`'s default encoding for `toString()` is UTF-8. So you will not be able to see the individual bytes any longer with that encoding. Instead, you will need to explicitly use the `'latin1'` encoding (e.g. `Buffer.from([0xcb, 0x98, 0x1b]).toString('latin1')`), which is a single-byte encoding (making the result the equivalent of `'\xcb\x98\x1b'`).

Answer (score 2):

[`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) works on strings. This means that the `Buffer` is being implicitly cast to a string by the `toString` method.

In doing so, the bytes are read as a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) string, as UTF-8 is the default encoding. From [Node's Buffer documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end):

> ```
> buf.toString([encoding[, start[, end]]])
> ```
>
> `encoding` `<string>` The character encoding to decode to. **Default:** `'utf8'`
>
> ...

`0xcb` and `0x98` are read as a single UTF-8 character (`˘`), thus the third byte ends up being at the 1 index, not the 2 index.

One option might be to explicitly call the `toString` method with a different encoding, but I'm thinking regex is probably not the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to return an array containing values not equal to `0x1b`

```
new Buffer([0xcb, 0x98, 0x1b].filter(byte => byte !== 0x1b))
```